# GitLab don't serve 404.html error page from root repo

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-pages

I have created `username.gitlab.io` repo with `index.html` and `404.html` pages, which have to be deployed automatically.

After deploy if I open in browser address `username.gitlab.io` it shows well `index.html` page and if I open `username.gitlab.io/404.html` it shows well too.

**BUT!!**

If I try to open `username.gitlab.io/not_existing_file` it shows internal GitLab error page, but not mine.

**At the same time:**

If I create repo with `reponame` and same content, it serves `404.html` page well on `/reponame/not_existing_file` from that repo.

---

**What am I doing wrong?**

---

Internal GitLab error page says, that: `..you don't have the necessary permissions..`, but the repo `reponame` has the same permissions (and settings at all) as `username.gitlab.io`.

Has anyone faced this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The "[Creating a custom 404 page for your GitHub Pages site](http://Pchandrasekar)" dos mention a `/404.html`.

And yet, [gitlab-pages issue 183](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-pages/issues/183) points to [`error-page-demo/error-page-demo.gitlab.io`](https://gitlab.com/error-page-demo/error-page-demo.gitlab.io) which has the [same issue on a non-existing file](https://error-page-demo.gitlab.io/favicon.ico), even though the [`error-page-demo.gitlab.io/404.html`](https://error-page-demo.gitlab.io/404.html) does exist.

This is still pending, with [MR 130](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-pages/merge_requests/130) still open.

---

Update Nov. 2021: [exaucae](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13781069/exaucae) mentions in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59919251/gitlab-dont-serve-404-html-error-page-from-root-repo/59919844#comment123853940_59919844) that MR 130 has been merged along with [MR 263](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-pages/-/merge_requests/263) and fixed.

> So that's now possible.
>
> In fact, MR 263 will allow namespace domains to serve custom `404.html` files for public projects.
> It will also allow serving the same custom error page for private projects when there is a parent namespace domain and is public.

Comment: UPDATE:  MR 130 has been merged along with MR 263(https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-pages/-/merge_requests/263) and fixed.   So that's now possible. In fact, MR 263 will allow namespace domains to serve custom 404.html files
for public projects.
It will also allow serving the same custom error page for private projects
when there is a parent namespace domain and is public.

Comment: @exaucae Great news, thank you! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Roger that. Thank you!